# Trying to add mutation testing

Tags: ruby, mutation-testing

I'm trying to add mutation testing to a rails project, with

```
gem 'mutant-rspec'
```

in the Gemfile, which seems to install it correctly with bundler

```
Resolving dependencies...
...
Using mutant 0.8.12
Using actionpack 5.0.0.1
Using mutant-rspec 0.8.11
...
Bundle complete! 26 Gemfile dependencies, 112 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But after trying to do anything with mutant, I always get this error, when trying to start mutant:

```
ytg@yui:~/projects/rails_hello_world> mutant
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby23, which recognizes
warning: 2.3.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.3.1.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require': cannot load such file -- mutant/mutator/node (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mutant-0.8.12/lib/mutant.rb:91:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mutant-0.8.12/bin/mutant:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/mutant:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/mutant:23:in `<main>'
```

I think my installation is missing something, but I can't figure out: what is missing?

Comment: Try installing ruby 2.3.3

Comment: I'm on Linux. Different flavours of Linux differ in their ruby support, but one thing seems to be common: they're never on the latest version, even though somehow some ruby tools seem to be on the latest version. It never made a difference before. But those damn warnings are there, and the first advice I always get with every single issue I face is to get rid of them.
Thanks, but I don't think the difference between 2.3.1 and 2.3.3 is so big that it would cause this.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Or stop trying to do mutation testing?

Comment: I stopped trying for now